Confidence interval for the range using bootstrapping
I have a machine producing parts with a variance in their lengths, each pack consists of 5 of said parts ( they are supposed to be identical ) , a pack is considered refused if the range between the biggest part and the smallest part of the pack is greater than 5cm. I can measure the length of individual parts ( i sampled and measured 180 random parts out of the machine ), however i can't do any sampling or measurement on individual packs as they are packed on demand and it may take me a very long time.
I need to develop a confidence interval for the rejection rate of the packs.
PS: the distribution of the length is almost normal given a viz and the 180 failed to reject a wilk-shapiro test with a p-value of 16%.
The approach I am using is basically bootstrapping with a percentile method for confidence interval.
First i sample 100, out of the 180 i have, then i simulate 500 pack using said 100, and calculate the range for each pack and measure the proportion of rejected proportions, and repeat this process for 10000 times and use the percentile method to get my confidence interval.
To validate this approach, I assumed a normal random variable with random mean and std, then i sampled 500,000 5-pieces packs and got the proportion of rejected packs and i assumed this is the true proportion. Then i sampled 180 sample from my random variable and i ran my approach explained above and generated 1000 60% confidence intervals, to check if around 60% of them include the true value. However, every simulation i ran 100% of the intervals included the true value, even if i used a totally random discrete random variable, i get the same results. I can't understand how this is happening, I assume something is wrong with my simulation or bootstrapping routine, but i can't figured it out.

Well, we cannot tell if your simulation is correct without a reproducible example.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@wzbillings i can share my code but it's written in python, will that be fine?

As previously commented, w/o some actual data, it is hard to say what the problem is, and what it is due to (it may even be a bug in your code).
But I will still share some comments on your approach, which I am not sure I understand. So, indeed, I will not answer the question directly, but it may still be of help.
You say that your goal is to obtain a "confidence interval for the rejection rate of the packs" and that the approach chosen "is basically bootstrapping with a percentile method for confidence interval". So far so good.
To get that rejection rate bootstrap, you need to simulate the sampling distribution of the relection rate. The way I would approach this is to randomly sample a 5-pack out of your 180 samples (with replacement!), and then repeat this e.g. $N$ times (e.g. 100, but could be 50, 200, etc.). On that simulated sample of 100 5-packs, then compute the % rejected. This is your first estimate of the rejection rate. Now repeat the above B times (bootstrap amount). You now have a bootstrapped sampling distribution of the rejection rate; use whatever percentile of choice to get the CI.
To validate this method, you could still use your method, but not starting from the range's distribution. However, your rejection rate is a Bernoulli, no matter the range's distribution. A 5-pack is either rejected or not, with a probability $p$ (Bernoulli). So alternatively choose a rejection rate $p$. Now take B samples from the binomial distribution $B(N,p)$. For each, compute the estimated rejection rate $\hat p$. You now have a bootstrapped sampling distribution of the binomial. See what the percentile method gives you for a CI, and compare to the analytical binomial CI if you had observed exactly $p$.
Note that it is not clear why you first take 100 samples from your 180, and use that to simulate 100 5-packs; you should take 1 5-pack (with replacement!) from the original 180, and repeat this $N$ times to get an estimate of $p$. It is also not clear if these 100 are with or w/o replacement, and then if the 5-packs are with or w/o replacement. And in any case, this 2 step process seems unnecessary. I am not implying that this is the reason for what happened to your validation, but?

just to make sure that i understood correctly before i go ahead and try it, you're suggesting that instead of sampling out of the 180 then sampling the 5-packs ( i was sample with replacement btw) i should sample from the 180 the 5-packs from directly, correct?
So, short answer to why did i decide to do this is: i am a beginner and i dont really know what i am doing :D, so please excuse my ignorance.

No worries. Let us know if it helped.
